# checkout problem for Credit Card

Tags: magento2, credit-card

I hooked up in checkout a credit card.
But i encountered such a problem that the payment does not work, and does not even give any error.

[image]

Just worth the wait animation and no more. How can I fix this?
The console also has no errors.

Comment: What payment method you are using? Enable payment log for that method and can check the exact request and responses in var/log/payment.log file. If not try to find any information in debug, system and exception log files. You can also check it in your console by finding the response you are receiving in network tab

Comment: Could you check the exception log? Probably in var/log/exception.log

Comment: there are no errors regarding checkout on this logs...

Comment: i have this data

array (
    'result' => '0',
    'securetoken' => 'token',
    'securetokenid' => 'token',
    'respmsg' => 'Approved',
    'result_code' => '0',
  ),

which means result => 0 and  'result_code' => '0',